# Avoid replacing ascii charcodes with numbers via Vite/Esbuild compiler

Tags: typescript, ascii, vite, esbuild

Example source

```js
const scan = (path: PathParser) => {
  const { index, pathValue } = path;
  const code = pathValue.charCodeAt(index);

  if (code === 0x30/* 0 */) {
    path.param = 0;
    path.index += 1;
    return;
  }

  if (code === 0x31/* 1 */) {
    path.param = 1;
    path.index += 1;
    return;
  }
}
```

Both 0x30 and 0x31 are replaced with 48 and 49 respectively. I've added a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBwEMwwLwwBQAcFQBYC44oAnASzAHMAaGcgEwFMAPQsAVwFsAjB4gSlQA+GAG8AsACgYMUJFihGqGNjwA6YLgTEAwiEYBBKOnrM+AbkmTppAGYYFDVCjQAGJgGYXAegBUMFzA+XgLiUtIwXl4wdCBwIByONkjAAJ5W4cQMUGzEYBZhAL6WYbb2eo7Orh4AjL4w1YHBounSkdGxEPGJyWlh0pnZufnSRRIFQA) but that doesn't seem to be affected one bit.

I'm using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) for tooling and I suspect it has to do with its esbuild configuration.

Anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution?

Thanks

**Solved**: the problem was not related to the ascii code to number conversion, but a Typescript typo above the sample function here.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://tsplay.dev/m33qjm); how are they "replaced"?  Could you provide a [mre] including enough information for someone to see this for themselves?

Comment: I've added a playground link, but it's a strange case I've never met. I suspect it must have to do with my Vite compiler.

Comment: Well then ‍♂️ it's not reproducible or needs more info in the question (including any relevant tags and config info)

Comment: Let me rephrase that question real quick.

Comment: 0x30 is not a char code. It is an hexadecimal value that is equal to 48. 0x31 is equal to 49. So there is no problem here.

Comment: @Raphaël it's not doing what is expected to do.

Comment: I'm tagging this with "vite" in the hopes that someone who follows that tag can help you; this has little to do with TypeScript as far as I can tell.  Good luck!

Comment: @Raphaël indeed you are right, `0x30 === 48` evaluates to `true`, which is a good thing because it saves space, but I found out why it didn't work: my Typescript wasn't correct above this function. Thank you guys, we can close this one.